# Why does debuggers give you "undefined is not a function" instead of just telling you the name of the property/variable that is not a function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

What is the reason js debuggers gives you "undefined is not a function" instead of just telling you the name of the property/variable that is not a function?

example:

```
a = {
  aFunction: function(){...}
  notAFunction: "foo"
}

a.notAFunction()
```

Gives:

> undefined is not a function

This is more helpful:

> property "notAFunction" of object "a" is not a function

What are the exact obstacles?

Comment: `a.notAFunction` is evaluated first. The result is `undefined`. The part that actually raises an exception is the attempt to invoke `undefined` as a function. At that point, `undefined` has no idea that it came from `a` or `notAFunction`, it's just `undefined`.

Comment: That's what the error stack trace is for. What good would knowing what the name of the property be without knowing *where* the error occured?

Comment: Firefox says `TypeError: a.notAFunction is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be changing very soon, it might already be in Canary too.

Improved exception messages: https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/DdWkiKsvbA2