# Why is only the first case of my switch list working correctly?

Tags: javascript

For the life of me, I can't figure out what's wrong with it. When I run this script, the first 'STAY' case works just fine. Running any of the other cases gives me an error (undefined is not a function).

Ran it thru my JS checker and it looked ok on there. Googled it and everyone else I'm seeing with the same problem has been told their breaks are either used incorrectly or not there. All of the syntax looks right to me from what I've learned. Compared it against the sample 'game' and it looks very similar to how they did it. What am I doing wrong?! Thank you for any help

```
var user = prompt("You see God. Do you want to STAY, PUNCH HIM, or CRY?").toUpperCase();

switch(user) {
case 'STAY':
    var curious = prompt("Are you a curious person?").toUpperCase();
    var insight = prompt("Are you an insightful person?").toUpperCase();
    if (curious === "YES" && insight === "YES") {
        console.log("Maybe it was a good idea to stay and speak to him");
    } else if (curious === "YES" || insight === "YES") {
        console.log("Well, maybe you can scrunge up something to say");
    } else {
        console.log("Why would you stay if you have nothing intelligent to say?");
    }
    break;
case 'PUNCH HIM':
    var strong = prompt("Are you ridiculously stronger than God?").toUpperCase();
    var fast = prompt("Are you faster than a minute man?").toUpperCase();
    if (strong === "YES" && fast === "YES") {
        console.prompt("You still dead, but not as dead as you would've been");
    } else if (strong === "YES" || fast === "YES") {
        console.prompt("One ain't good enough, homie");
    } else {
        console.prompt("Slow and weak? Bad choice, dag");
    }
    break;
case 'CRY':
    var convincing = prompt("Are you superbly convincing with crying?").toUpperCase();
    var female = prompt("Are you a female?").toUpperCase();
    if (convincing === "YES" && female === "YES") {
        console.prompt("You'll prolly be ok, boo");
    } else if (convincing === "YES" || female === "YES") {
        console.prompt("Hope you're a female");
    } else {
        console.prompt("You dead!");
    }
    break;
default:
    console.prompt("Answer the question with the supplied answers");

}
```

Comment: Missing `;` after the last `}` before `break;`?

Comment: @sideroxylon: Why would a `;` be needed there?

Comment: Closing the statements with `;` is the conventional syntax.

Comment: @sideroxylon: Only when it's actually needed. I haven't seen a single library or script that places `;` after every `}` - because the `}` itself closes its own block. A possible exception is when the `}` marks the end of an object literal instead of a block, but there are absolutely no object literals in this code.

Comment: I was only referring to the last one - as every example of a switch statement I've seen or used finishes the last statement in each case with `;` - however I've just tested one without it, and it works fine.  So I concede.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `console.log` instead of `console.prompt`.

Comment: @Aditya: How is this not an answer? The OP is asking what is wrong with their code, and this tells them exactly that. In fact, it's the *correct* answer.

Comment: yes... and I don't see anything else wrong other than this console.prompt issue. the code works fine for other choices.

Comment: @Jeremy H: In fairness, [the error message that you received isn't *at all* helpful either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612341/why-does-debuggers-give-you-undefined-is-not-a-function-instead-of-just-tellin).